# How to clear the session and only visit an about page after login?

Tags: go, session, cookies

This code has two parts. One is to set and clear the session and the second part is login and logout.

**What it does?**

In the second part, If an email and password are found in the database and the match is `true` then it set the session and move to the `about()` function which has an about file. If the logout is called then it clears the session and redirects to the home page.

**What it should do?**

The problem is that even if I am logged out and the session is cleared, I can still visit an about page. I don't want to be allowed to visit an about page if I am not logged in.

**First part**

```
var cookieHandler = securecookie.New(
    securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(64),
    securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32),
)

func setSession(email, password string, res http.ResponseWriter) {
    value := map[string]string{ "email": email, "password": password}
    encoded, err := cookieHandler.Encode("session", value)
    if err == nil {
        cookie := &http.Cookie{ Name:  "session", Value: encoded, Path:  "/"}
        http.SetCookie(res, cookie)
    }
}

func clearSession(res http.ResponseWriter) {
    cookie := &http.Cookie{ Name: "session", Value: "", Path: "/", MaxAge: -1}
    http.SetCookie(res, cookie)
}
```

**Second part**

```
func about(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("template didn't execute", nil)
    }
}

func loginAuth(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    email := req.FormValue("email")
    password := req.FormValue("password")
    match := database.Findaccount(email, password)
    if match == true {
        setSession(email, password, res)
        about(res, req)
        fmt.Println("You're logged in")
    } else {
        tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "login.html", nil)
        fmt.Println("Enter the correct email or password")
    }
}

func logout(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    clearSession(res)
    http.Redirect(res, req, "/", 302)
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide `about(...)` implementation. It is kinda out of the topic, but how `cookieHandler.encode` and `database.Findaccount` methods work? The suspicion that the password may somehow be stored in a cookie is alarming.

Comment: @Jaroslaw I updated the code and wrote `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", nil)` in about section and `database.Findaccount()` is a function that I am importing from the database file to find the data.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Sadly i don't see the code of `about` function. As for the `cookieHandler`, could add imports because securecookie does not look like a standard go package. Regarding `database.Findaccount`, it makes me wonder if the database stores passwords or hashes of those passwords.

Comment: I again updated the code adding an about function and the database stores the password as hashes and `database.Findaccount()` find and convert them back into original format.

Comment: @Jaroslaw I am waiting for the response.

Comment: So basically you don't check that the user is logged in as a part of `about` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things you don't want to do, in general:

- Don't use cookie encoder directly. Use a cookie session store.
- Don't call an handler within an handler, prefer a redirect. This should prevent writing twice the headers/body on the response.
- Don't pass the user/password in the cookie, even encoded, in 2021 we may even prevent sending that through the form at all (you might consider sending only a hash and re hash the hash on the server side to figure out if things are good to go).

Few things you always want to do:

- Write tests.
- Make use of middlewares.
- Always provide small reproducible examples.

That being said, I have written a lookalike code with some stubs (mostly for db), I removed template support (i was not in the mood to write HTML) and more importantly I wrote tests !!

To the question `How to clear the session` :
Delete the values from the store, write the store

To the question `and only visit an about page after login?`:
Wrap that handler with a middleware that verifies login data attached to the user cookie store

```golang
-- main.go --
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

// Note: Don't store your key in your source code. Pass it via an
// environmental variable, or flag (or both), and don't accidentally commit it
// alongside your code. Ensure your key is sufficiently random - i.e. use Go's
// crypto/rand or securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32) and persist the result.

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(
    securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32),
)

//emulate db package
func dbLookupUser(user, pwd string) bool {
    return user == "user" && pwd == "pwd"
}
func dbLookupHash(h string) bool {
    return h == hash("user", "pwd")
}

func hash(s ...interface{}) string {
    hr := sha256.New()
    fmt.Fprint(hr, s...)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", hr.Sum(nil))
}

// hashKey is a typed key for the session map store to prevent unintented overwrites.
type hashKey string

func init() {
    gob.Register(hashKey(""))
}

func loginAuth(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    email := req.FormValue("email")
    password := req.FormValue("password")
    match := dbLookupUser(email, password)
    if match == true {
        session, _ := store.Get(req, "session-name")
        session.Values["hash"] = hash(email, password)
        // Save it before we write to the response/return from the handler.
        err := session.Save(req, res)
        if err == nil {
            // about(res, req) // don't!
            // the about handler might want to setup its own http response headers
            // That would conflict with what we did here.
            // prefer a redirect
            http.Redirect(res, req, "/about", http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(res, "try again") // use a templatee instead!
        // tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "login.html", nil)
    }
}

func logout(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(req, "session-name")
    delete(session.Values, hashKey("hash"))
    _ = session.Save(req, res)
    http.Redirect(res, req, "/", 302)
}

func about(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(res, "welcome to about page")
}

func requireLogin(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")
        var h string
        if x, ok := session.Values[hashKey("hash")]; ok {
            h = x.(string)
        }

        var match bool
        if h != "" {
            match = dbLookupHash(h)
        }

        if !match {
            // Write an error and stop the handler chain
            http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }
        next(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", loginAuth)
    r.HandleFunc("/logout", logout)
    r.HandleFunc("/about", requireLogin(about))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", r))
}


-- main_test.go --
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/url"
    "testing"
)

func TestLogin(t *testing.T) {

    req := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Set("email", "user")
    form.Set("password", "pwd")
    req.Form = form

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    loginAuth(w, req)

    resp := w.Result()
    // body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if wanted := http.StatusFound; resp.StatusCode != wanted {
        t.Fatalf("invalid response code, got=%v wanted=%v", resp.StatusCode, wanted)
    }
    // implement more check
}

func TestLoginFailure(t *testing.T) {

    req := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Set("email", "!user")
    form.Set("password", "!pwd")
    req.Form = form

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    loginAuth(w, req)

    resp := w.Result()
    // body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if wanted := http.StatusOK; resp.StatusCode != wanted {
        t.Fatalf("invalid response code, got=%v wanted=%v", resp.StatusCode, wanted)
    }
    // implement more check
}

func TestAboutNotLogged(t *testing.T) {

    req := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com/foo", nil)

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    requireLogin(about)(w, req)

    resp := w.Result()
    // body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if wanted := http.StatusForbidden; resp.StatusCode != wanted {
        t.Fatalf("invalid response code, got=%v wanted=%v", resp.StatusCode, wanted)
    }
    // implement more check
}

func TestAboutLogged(t *testing.T) {

    req := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com/foo", nil)

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    session, _ := store.Get(req, "session-name")
    session.Values[hashKey("hash")] = hash("user", "pwd")
    err := session.Save(req, w)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    hdr := w.Header()
    req.Header.Add("Cookie", hdr["Set-Cookie"][0])

    w = httptest.NewRecorder()
    requireLogin(about)(w, req)

    resp := w.Result()
    // body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if wanted := http.StatusOK; resp.StatusCode != wanted {
        t.Fatalf("invalid response code, got=%v wanted=%v", resp.StatusCode, wanted)
    }
    // implement more check
}
```